# inception models backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I want to create (sit down please) a collection of models. Those models should contains an other collection. witch havea name, color and a collection of expenses.

Here are my 3 objects :

```
//model : Expense
var Expense = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        date: '',
        cost: 0,
        comment: ''
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('expense : created');
    }
});
//model : Category
var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        color: '#333',
        expenses: Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Expense
        })
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('expense : created');
    }
});
//model : Wallet
var Wallet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        categories: Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Category
        })
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('wallet : created');
    }
});
```

I made researches for 2 days for nested models, but I really can't find a way to :

- add categories on my wallet
- add expenses on my categories
- modifiy them

Do you think that [backbone nested models](https://github.com/blittle/backbone-nested-models/) or [backbone relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) could really help me for this ? They seems pretty heavy…

I hope my answer is not too silly, I'm a starter with backbone, and it is not really easy to get in !

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use backbone plugins for your nested models you can do something like this:

```
//model : Expense
var Expense = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        date: '',
        cost: 0,
        comment: ''
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('expense : created');
    }
});

//collection : Expenses
var Expenses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Expense
});

//model : Category
var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    color: '#333'
  },
  initialize: function () {
    this._ensureExpenses();
    console.log('expense : created');
  },
  parse: function(data){
    if(data.expenses){
      this._ensureExpenses();
      this.expenses.set(data.expenses, {parse: true});
    }
    return _.omit(data, 'expenses'); 
  },    
  toJSON: function(){
    return _.extend(_.clone(this.attributes), {
      expenses: this.expenses.toJSON()
    });
  },
  _ensureExpenses: function(){
    this.expenses = this.expenses || new Expenses();
  }
});

//collection : Categories
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Category
});

//model : Wallet
var Wallet = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function () { 
    this._ensureCategories();
    console.log('wallet : created');
  },
  parse: function(data){
    if(data.categories){
      this._ensureCategories();
      this.categories.set(data.categories, {parse: true});
    }
    return _.omit(data, 'categories'); 
  },
  toJSON: function(){
    return _.extend(_.clone(this.attributes), {
      categories: this.categories.toJSON()
    });
  },
  _ensureCategories: function(){
    this.categories = this.categories || new Categories();
  }
});
```

If you don't need serialize wallet to plain JS object or to JSON you can remove toJSON methods.

You can test it here: http://jsbin.com/luruvifi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: wow, this is great ! I'll get in the code to understand it now, but it seems perfect !
To add an expense or a category, should I use get/set or do this like in vanilla js (myWallet.Expenses.push({…})) ?

Comment: You can add new model to collection with collection.add (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add): `myWallet.categories.first().expenses.add({date: '24/12/2013', cost: 4});`